# How to setup private WiFi network in a garden building, using house internet connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

We have a log cabin being built in our garden, to be used as a workspace. It has independent electrical supply and is about 30m from the house, line of sight just.

We need to get WiFi in the cabin and do not want a dedicated internet connection e.g 4G SIM. A cable between the two buildings isn't possible.

Our home WiFi doesn't reach and I don't simply want a repeater anyway... I would like a WiFi router/access point in the cabin with a separate WiFi network, which somehow links to our house WiFi.

What type of equipment/configuration allows this? I can get cat6 from our home router to the external wall nearest the cabin, but what I put on the outside of both buildings and how I set it all up is the question. Trying to search for products I'm drowned in generic access point devices.

Comment: have you looked in the Nanostations by Ubiquiti.  I installed a pair for a friend who had a house about 100M from the main house.  It has worked well apparently.

Comment: I'm not after specific product recommendations but happy to hear them especially referenced in an answer describing how they'd be used. Thanks

Comment: You may wish to reconsider running outdoor Ethernet. I have a Ubiquiti Lite AP here in my home office and it works well. It is very inexpensive, but needs an Ethernet hookup to the main router and a POE injector at the main router to power the Ubiquiti AP

Comment: So whilst not recommending anything to maybe make it easier to find - I have LigoDLB Echo devices - Ubiquiti are have been regularly recommended to me , however the LigoDLB Echo units were sightly cheaper with the mounting, cables and shipping I wanted than the Ubiquiti units I found

Comment: @john apart from the issue of physically laying the cable which isn't a trivial job to do properly, I've been advised of potential earthing issues which put me off!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to search for (based on what I tried) is PTP or PtMP Wifi This is Point To (Multi-) Point -  You should find various consumer grade products  which provide directional antenna. You should look for units with the physical characteristics you need

You should check specifically what mounting is included and what is not.

You may want highly directional antennas to help and the ability to provide better LOS by putting the units on a pole.

The units I have are quite small 100*100 mm square with a simple cable tie to mount on a pole and powered by Passive POE and thus require only one cable.  The cable entry is watered proofed and my particular supplied provided stronger cables to length with cable glands fitted to allow waterproof entry into my shed.